# Google Ads Api discrepancy between campaign & detail_placement_view Report

Tags: video, youtube, google-ads-api

I'm experiencing discrepancies between two queries I use to extract statistics from my video campaigns in Google Ads. Typically, I use the first query below to obtain general statistics for my video campaigns:

```
SELECT 
    segments.date, 
    campaign.name, 
    campaign.id, 
    metrics.cost_micros, 
    metrics.video_views, 
    metrics.impressions, 
    metrics.clicks, 
    metrics.conversions  
FROM campaign  
WHERE campaign.id IN (<google_ads_campaign_id>) 
AND segments.date >= '2024-02-01' 
AND segments.date <= '2024-02-01' 
AND campaign.status IN (ENABLED, PAUSED)
```

However, I'm attempting to expand my analysis to include the segment of YouTube videos through which my ads have been displayed. To achieve this, I've created a second query that includes the detail placement view report:

```
SELECT 
    detail_placement_view.group_placement_target_url, 
    detail_placement_view.placement, 
    detail_placement_view.placement_type, 
    detail_placement_view.target_url, 
    segments.date, 
    campaign.name, 
    campaign.id, 
    metrics.cost_micros, 
    metrics.video_views, 
    metrics.impressions, 
    metrics.clicks, 
    metrics.conversions  
FROM detail_placement_view  
WHERE campaign.id IN (<google_ads_campaign_id>) 
AND segments.date >= '2024-02-01' 
AND segments.date <= '2024-02-01' 
AND campaign.status IN (ENABLED, PAUSED)
```

My issue is that I'm noticing significant discrepancies between the data obtained from these two queries, particularly in metrics such as impressions. My goal is to understand whether these discrepancies are within normal variation or if there's an underlying issue causing them.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to address this discrepancy and ensure the accuracy of my analyses.